# Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'.... Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbConextOptions

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework for a web application.
I am trying to create a new migration, but I am getting the following error:

```
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[PMSX.Infrastructure.Persistence.Database.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'PMSX.Infrastructure.Persistence.Database.ApplicationDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)`
```

Here is my ApplicationDbContext

`

```
namespace PMSX.Infrastructure.Persistence.Database
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; } = default!;
        public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; } = default!;
        public DbSet<StockHolding> StockHoldings { get; set; } = default!;
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; } = default!;
        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; } = default!;

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Stock>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

`
And here is my Program.cs:

```
`
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString,
    assembly => assembly.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));
services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();`
```

I've been trying several other solutions I found on Stackoverflow, but they are not working. I am hoping something in my code can be spotted that is causing the issues....

I added --verbose and tried to look through the error. I tried to strip out everything from the ApplicationDBContext. I made sure to set the web application as the startup project. I checked to make sure the ApplicationDBContext has a constructor.

UPDATE: When I run "dotnet ef migrations" commands, the program.cs is not being run, so the contextoptions are never passed. Why is it not running program.cs?

Answer (score 0):

I created .NET core webapp to do Entity framework migrations.
I installed below packages for Entity Framework migrations.

[image]

I added two classes Developer and Country to create table in database.

[image]

I created dbcontex class as below

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication4.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication4.DataLayer
{
    public class DeveloperDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DeveloperDbContext(DbContextOptions
    <DBContextname> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Developer> Developer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DeveloperEntityConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I mention my connection string in appsettings.json file as below

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DeveloperDatabase": "data source=<serverName>; initial catalog=<dbname>;integrated security=true"
  }
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I add startup to the project.
I added below code for startup to know the dbContext

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<DBContextName>
           (o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.
            GetConnectionString("DeveloperDatabase")));
```

I added below code to startup to create database if there is database with that name

```
db.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Program.cs:

```
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

When I run It executed successfully
Image for reference:

[image]

Migration done successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

Database is created in my server successfully.

Image for reference:

[image]

It worked for me please check from your end.